# Post request to Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I know usually it is impossible to handle the Post a request to a Visualforce page. But I kind of need a decent way to resolve the following scenario:

In my VF page one, I have a button to open VF page two. And by opening VF page two, I need to pass several variables. One of them is an Array.

One option to me is obviously use JSON to serialize the array, URL-encode it and pass it as a query string variable. But that solution would be pretty ugly and the query string can easily be too long. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't we call child VF page jasvcript and pass the array in that ?

Comment: @Ratan do you have a sample code on how to do it?

Comment: Lence.. Currently I dont have(I need to research) but mean while you can ask this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask I am pretty sure you will get your ans.

Comment: @Ratan I guess it is a bit different. For general web pages, I guess the best way is just to use a post request and handle it at server side, which is not an option in Salesforce though. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @Ratan Also, I am quite tempted to handle it at server side if it is possible. Doing it via browser variable is possible, but still pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data through your *VF controller variables*.
Use `PageReference.setRedirect(false);` when redirecting to your second page.